# what is the best way of doing a http post in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post

Tried posting this:
**{grant_type: password, password: 123456, username: user1234}** with the below code

```
Future<HttpClientResponse> apiRequest(String url, String username, String password) async {
Map jsonMap = {'grant_type':'password','password':password,'username':username};
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
request.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
request.add(utf8.encode((jsonMap.toString())));
print((jsonMap.toString()));
return await request.close();
}
```

but response says **{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The mandatory 'grant_type' parameter is missing."}**

trying it on postman getting a different result

[screen shot of response with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok92u.png)

Comment: are you sure the response is from the request, and not from flutter itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best way i think. Currently I use Retrofit For Dart, which is quite convenient because it generates the actual implementation.

For example,

```
@POST('/oauth/token')
@Headers(Constant.HEADER)
Future<LoginResponse> loginByEmail(@Query("email") String email, 
@Query("password") String password, @Query("grant_type") String grantType);
```

will become

```
@override
loginByEmail(email, password, grantType) async {
  ArgumentError.checkNotNull(email, 'email');
  ArgumentError.checkNotNull(password, 'password');
  ArgumentError.checkNotNull(grantType, 'grantType');
  const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
  final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{
    'email': email,
    'password': password,
    'grant_type': grantType
  };
  final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
  final Response<Map<String, dynamic>> _result = await _dio.request(
    '/oauth/token',
    queryParameters: queryParameters,
    options: RequestOptions(
        method: 'POST',
        headers: <String, dynamic>{

        },
        extra: _extra,
        baseUrl: baseUrl),
    data: _data);
  final value = LoginResponse.fromJson(_result.data);
  return Future.value(value);
}
```

Comment: ended up using the approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know the method you are using, but I'll show you my method that works, and it should help you understand the structure of the request.

Server-side code shows:

```
POST - /api/getInfo

Request:

{
user_phone: ''
notes: ''
}

Response:

{
status: ''
}
```

So this being the server-side code, this request (a post request) needs a variable user_phone, and a variable notes.  It gives us a response of status.

So what I would do to make a single request of this server would be the following:

```
String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password')); // <--- Generate the Basic Auth string
http.Response response = await http.get(
  'https://myRandomServer.com/api/getInfo',
  headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth}, // <--- Authorization in header
  body: {'user_phone': '5555555555', 'notes': 'Some note'}, // <--- Data required in body of request
);

if (response.body != null) {
  Map data = jsonDecode(responseStatus.body); // <--- Decoding from json file response
  myStatus = data.['status']; // <----  Piece of information I need
}
```

Now there are more ways than this, however, this should help you figure out what might be wrong with your original code, or how it needs to be modified to do what you're trying to do.